# best way to flatten n-level array into 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know there are a lot of ways to flatten an array in javascript, but I want to know what's the best way to flatten an n-level array into a 2D array

Input array looks like this : `[[[[1,2]]],[2,3]]` i need to convert this into `[[1,2],[2,3]]`

I tried using array.flat() but it flattens only 1 step and I also tried array.flat(Infinity) but it flattens the whole array into 1D array

the problem is am not sure how deeply nested my input array is. I could think of iterating recursively but am looking if js has any optimised&ready-made way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried lodash methods?

Comment: can you suggest which one to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `map` and `flat(Infinity)` methods to flatten each sub-array to 1D.

```js
const flatDeep = data => data.map(e => e.flat(Infinity))
console.log(flatDeep([[[[1,2]]],[2,3]]))
console.log(flatDeep([[[[1,2]]],[2,[[[3, [4]]]]]]))
```

Comment: This looks good but it doesn't keep the last level of grouping intact.. i want `[[[[1,2],[3,4]]],[2,3]]` to be converted to `[[1,2],[2,3],[2,3]]` not `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3]]`

Comment: @aravind_reddy So what should be the result in this case `[[[[1,2]]],[2,[[[3, [4]]]]]]`?

Comment: it should be [[1,2],[2,3,4]] i guess

Comment: @aravind_reddy So what is the logic there?

Comment: sorry i think what you gave is good I will post the other requirements in another question altogether

Answer (score 0):

`Iterate` the array and then use `Array.flat(Infinity)` method.

```js
const list = [[[[1,2]]],[2,3],[[3,4]]]
const result = [];
for (value of list) {
  result.push(value.flat(Infinity));
}
console.log(result);
```